# Export a list of arrays to Excel

Tags: php, arrays, excel, export-to-excel

I'm trying to export a list of arrays to Excel in order to create a spreadsheet.  Basically, we enter a new campaign and select a list of customers that want to be a part of the campaign.  What is then generated is a List that includes the title of the campaign, all the customer #'s that are included in the campaign, the list of the dealers, and the last column is their URLs.  I have an Export button created, but am not sure how to pass these arrays through the URL, using a query string.  The list is stored in the database, but the Customer Numbers and the URLs are being pulled from a different table based on the Customers chosen.  So I am trying to avoid calling to multiple tables in the database to accomplish this.  Is there an easy way to accomplish passing these values over to Excel?

I have tried the following and it wasn't working:

exportCampaign.php?promo_list&customer_num[]&dealer_ids[]&guid[]

Comment: How about store unique ids for GET params. Then URL will look like http://exampl/exportCampaign.php?id=foo then script will select data (real IDs) from some SQL table based on ID. That will allow you to store tons of data.

Comment: I am storing the lists of campaigns in the database.  However, when pulling the list to display to the admin users in the backend, it's pulling the info not only from the table that the campaign title and customer id's are stored in, but also from another 2 tables (i think i said only one in my above question) in order to get the Customer #'s (these are generated by the client) and their respective URLs.

Comment: Still see no problem, store data generated by the client, join with other data, work on data, create output.